# How to get value of master Page textbox on content page Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, master-pages

I have a master page where two text boxes "fromdate" and "todate" has been putted.Now i am using this master page with content page .According to my need i have to get the value of these two text boxes on client page from Jquery for formatting of the query and sending it to the server side code..

i know how to get the value of textboxes decalred on content page but i dont know how i can get for master page through jquery..

Here is my Master page Code..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Style="left: 400px; position: absolute; top: 158px; font-size: small;" Width="95px" Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Style="left: 113px; position: absolute; top: 158px; font-size: small;" Width="95px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: post some code so we can see what you have

Comment: @Rajesh Sir I have posted my Master page textboxes code

Comment: Since the page will automatically include master page contents, you should be able to use jQuery to get the values of textboxes